# How do I continue my work flow when a new tab opens up in the browser using UI path

Tags: uipath

When I click on help in some website for example,then a new tab pops open and I want to continue my work flow in the new pop tab using UI path

Answer (score 1):

Try to use “Attach Window” activity and indicate the new tab that you need to work with.